# Is the resolvent norm the same for all metric spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let

$$R_\lambda = |P-I\lambda|^{-1}$$

be the resolvent norm of some operator $P$.

Let furthermore $u(x)$ be an eigenfunction of $P$. Let $u(x) \in L^2$, and let $P$ be a bounded differential operator on the space $[a,b]$.

The term "resolvent norm" seems confusive, as it seems related to "the norm of an operator". However, it is only the inverse of the absolute value of of $P-I\lambda$.

So if that function is defined on $L^2$ then the norm of the function is $$||u(x)||=
 \left( \int \vert f  \vert^2 \, d\mu\right)^{1/2}$$.

It is clear then that the resolvent "norm" has nothing to do with the norm of the element in $L^2$, and therefore I ask:

Is the resolvent norm is the same for all metric spaces?

Thanks